# MsDeploy dbDacFx provider: tries to export table which does not exist in my database

Tags: msdeploy

When I am trying to sync database to a file - it fails with error:

> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: (3/15/2016 12:00:11 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. ---> System.Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Table with schema "dbo" and name "dtproperties" was specified for data import or export, but does not exist in the database schema.

I do not have such a table in my database.

Here is command I am using

> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -Verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=db1\sql2012;Database=Sitecore_Core;User ID=sa;Password=very_extra-securie-pws",computername="https://mytargetcomp.local:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=some-site",username=administrator,password=adminOasssa,authtype=basic -allowuntrusted  -Dest:dbDacFx=c:\Northwind.dacpac -debug

**ADD 1:**
I tried to add proposed by chief7 properties:

> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -Verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=db1\sql2012;Database=Sitecore_Core;User ID=sa;Password=very_extra-securie-pws",IgnoreExtendedProperties=true,DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource=true,computername="https://mytargetcomp.local:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=some-site",username=administrator,password=adminOasssa,authtype=basic -allowuntrusted  -Dest:dbDacFx=c:\Northwind.dacpac -debug

But still the same failure.

**ADD 2:**
I supposed that problem can be in WmSvc, but, even when executing locally - I still experience this issue with following cmd:

> msdeploy.exe -Verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="Data Source=db1\sql2012;Database=SiteCore_Core;User ID=sa;Password=password",IgnoreExtendedProperties=true,DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource=true -Dest:dbDacFx=d:\Northwind.dacpac,IgnoreExtendedProperties=true,DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource=true -debug

Answer (score 1):

That's a system table.  You can configure the MSDeploy to ignore it by adding the following flags (or similar).

```
-Dest:dbDacFx=c:\Northwind.dacpac,IgnoreExtendedProperties=true
```

I'm not positive this is the exact property to use but I believe so. The full list is at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.aspx

Comment: Did you check the link I provided for other DacPac deploy options that may need to be set?

Comment: Yes, but with no luck :(